# The RBF kernel of Support Vector Machine

Tags: machine-learning

The non-linear kernels allow the SVM to separate non-linear data linearly in a high dimensional space. The RBF kernel is probably the most popular non-linear kernel.

I was told that the RBF kernel is Gaussian, and therefore is infinitely differentive. With this property, the RBF kernel can map the data from a low dimensional space to an INFINITE dimensional space. I have 2 questions:

1) Could anyone explain why the number of feature space after mapping is corresponding to the derivatives of the kernel? I am not clear on this part.
2) There are many non-linear kernels, such as polynomial kernel, and I believe they are also able to map the data from a low dimensional space to an infinite dimensional space. But why the RBF kernel is more popular then them?

Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) Could anyone explain why the number of feature space after mapping
>   is corresponding to the derivatives of the kernel? I am not clear on
>   this part.

It has nothing to do with being differentiable, linear kernel is also infinitely differentiable and does not map to any higher dimensional space, whoever told you that it is the reason -- lied or did not understand the math behind it. The infinite dimension comes from the mapping

```
phi(x) = Nor(x, sigma^2)
```

in other words you are mapping your point into **function** being a Gaussian distribution, which is an element of L^2 space, infinitely dimension space of continuous function, where scalar product is defined as an integral of multiplication of functions, so

```
<f,g> = int f(a)g(a) da
```

and as such

```
<phi(x),phi(y)> = int Nor(x,sigma^2)(a)Nor(y,sigma^2)(a) da 
                = X exp(-(x-y)^2 / (4sigma^2) )
```

for some normalising constant `X` (which is completely unimportant). In other words, Gaussian kernel is a scalar product between two functions, which have infinite dimensions.

> 2) There are many non-linear kernels, such as polynomial kernel, and I
>   believe they are also able to map the data from a low dimensional
>   space to an infinite dimensional space. But why the RBF kernel is more
>   popular then them?

Polynomial kernel maps into feature space with `O(d^p)` dimensions, where `d` is input space dimension and `p` is polynomial degree, so it is far from being infinite. Why is Gaussian popular? Because it works, and is quite easy to use and fast to compute. From theoretical point of view it also has guarantees of learning any arbitrary set of points (with small enough variances used).

Comment: Thank you so much for such a detailed reply. Would you mind to explain why the'function being a Gaussian distribution has infinitely dimension space of continuous function' and indicate which parameter of the Gaussian kernel denote the number of dimensions? （may I understand like this: the value of the kernel function is the output of the inner product after mapping. Therefore, for Gaussian kernel, a exponential function, if the (x-y)^2 becomes sufficiently large, the corresponding output value will increase exponentially to infinite?)   Thank you for your patience.....

Comment: Try to imagine function as a **vector**, in "normal" vectors you have something like `v=[11,22,33,44]`, so you have `v[1]=11, v[2]=22, v[3]=33, v[4]=44`, `4` dimensions, each with real value. Now think about a function **like a vector**, you have `v(a)=exp( -(x-a)^2/2sigma^2 )`, which is defined **for each real a**, so you have inifinitely many dimensions, not just a=1,2,3,4 but also `a=pi`, `a=-123/23+pi` etc. There is no "parameter in gaussian kernel denoting its dimension", it is **always infinite**.

Comment: once you think about the vector `v` as a function it is easy to comprehend, that scalar product becomes integral as the "infinite equivalent of summation", `<v1,v2> = int v1(a)*v2(a) da`

Comment: Sorry to put you out...but would you mind to say more on 'think about a function like a vector'? I am a little confused on how to make this imagination:1) It looks you assume 'a' has infinite length. For an inner product after mapping: k(x,a), 'x' denotes original data from model and 'a' denote input data being processed, the length of 'a' should be finite; 2) 'for each real a', assuming a  is a vector, can we find the 3.14th element of the vector 'v'(v(a))? and how to understand this imagination? 3) 'it is always infinite':what is the 'it'?      Thank you for your patience once more...

Comment: For instance, assume: v1=[1 2 3] while v2=[ 4 5 6] and how to do the integral: int v1(3.14)*v2(3.14) da? and how to understand this integral? why the kernel function is the integral like this?   I swear this is not a rhetorical question, but I feel a little confused on this concept...

Comment: you are confusing **feature mapping** and **kernel**. I am talking about `phi(x)=Nor(x,sigma^2)[a]` which is **a function of a**, it is **not** `K(x,a)` (it may look alike, because integrals of gaussians is also a gaussian, but `K(x,a)` is a **number**, while `phi(x)` is a **function**). So you have a function `v=phi(x)`, such that `v(a)=Nor(x,sigma^2)[a]`, and this function has **inifite domain**, the whole real set, which makes it infinite dimensional vector

Comment: If you have x1=[1 2 3] and x2=[4 5 6] then `phi(x1) = Nor( [1 2 3], sigma^2)[a]` and `phi(x2) = Nor( [4 5 6], sigma^2)[a]`. So one of them is a **function** (gaussian) centered in [1 2 3] and other in [4 5 6]. Now you multiply these two functions, and get `(phi(x1)*phi(x2))[a]` which is also a function of `a`, defined as `(phi(x1)*phi(x2))[a] = phi(x1)[a]*phi(x2)[a]`. Now you **integrate** this function to get the final **kernel value**. It happens, that up to the normalization constant it is **value in x2 of a gaussian centered in x1**, but it is only because gaussians integrate like this.

Comment: Sorry I still feel confused.Can I understand like this: 1) actually, the kernel function does not do any 'mapping'; it is JUST a value EQUIVALENT to the value of <phi(x),phi(y)> after mapping, which can be an INFINITE dimensional space for RBF kernel? 2) The reason why <phi(x),phi(y)> can be infinitely long is the Gaussian curve is infinitely wide, containing infinite subsets.      If my understand is right.... every continuous function has infinite elements...and <phi(x),phi(y)> for other kernels should also be infinitely long...

Comment: You seem to lack basic understanding of what is happening here. Your understanding is completely wrong. The dimensionality is the dimensionality of the space onto which **phi** maps. If you forget about **mapping** you do not have access to the space of which **dimension we are talking about**. Comments are not the place for math education, if you still feel confused, you can post other question.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I just watched a tutorial video and I think can understand this issue: using Taylor's expansion, the <phi(x),phi(y)> using Gaussian kernel can be decomposed to INFINITE terms, and this expansion can be regarded as a function of 'a'(as you mentioned) in an INFINITE space.    I think this time it may look reasonable.

Comment: I opened another question on this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57494858/how-would-phi-of-the-gaussian-rbf-kernel-map-a-100-by-3-dimensional-feature-matr